# ¿Por qué me sale un error al hacer un POST?

Tags: python, json, cabeceras-http

Estoy intentando hacer un POST con este código en Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#
#Post 
#
import requests, json

url = 'http://exemple.es/GetOrderInfo' #Esta no es la url real
data = { "order": "1234567", "locale": "es", "email": "test@test.com", 
    "command": "NADA", 
    "token": "123455678910" }
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
print r.status_code
print r.json()
```

y la repuesta que recibo es:

```
400
{u'Message': u'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'}
```

Sigo sin saber el por qué de este error, creo que la cabecera está bien, porque según he leído el error 400 es por un header de length=0

Answer (score 2):

Intenta:

```
import json
from requests import post as POST
def request(request_body):
    rq = POST('http://exemple.es/GetOrderInfo',
          data=json.dumps(request_body), timeout=20)
    try:
        resp = rq.json()
    except Exception:
        resp = ""

data = { "order": "1234567", "locale": "es", "email": "test@test.com", 
"command": "NADA", "token": "123455678910" }
print request(data)
```

Comment: Bueno ahora sale: None, sigo sin comprender el por qué no se envía la petición. El error que sale ahora es el 415. Muchas gracias por el código, es mil veces más claro el tuyo.

Comment: En todo caso puede ser problema de la API, prueba la API desde el postman

Comment: Como dato, si añado la cabecera: 
`headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}`
El error que sale es el 400 de antes, ahora pruebo el postman. Gracias!

Comment: Puedes añadir el header pero no debería ser necesario:
`headers = {
        'content-type': "application/json"
    }
    rq = POST('http://exemple.es/GetOrderInfo',
          data=json.dumps(request_body), headers=headers, timeout=20)`

Comment: Sí, eso es lo que he hecho. Con postman obtengo lo mismo:
`{
  "Message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
}`
Ahora sí que podría decir que es cosa del servidor y no del código?

Comment: Si es cosa de la API, o puede ser que no acepte json si no "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" revisa su documentación.

Comment: Haciendo curl -I de la url he obtenido esto:
`HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Allow: POST
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 73
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8`
Entonces por lo que entiendo, sí que acepta JSON y el content-length creo que hace referencia al data, que envio, así que lo he reducido a 73 exacto, respetando el nombre de las variables, y aún así obtengo:
`400
{u'Message': u'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'}`